# Creating Relationship Creates Additional Columns in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, relational-database

I have the attached image below of tables I have created in MySQL Workbench. The tables shows a one-to-one connection between a donor and its contact.

[image]

My challenge is that anytime I create the relationship, it creates another column as seen circled red in the image. This does not allow me to insert data into the contact table and it gives me an error of an unknown column in the execution of my insert syntax.

I want to know why I do have that column created and also is there a way I can work around it to allow me inset data to the table without any errors cos i have read that they are indexes and are thus good for speedy searches throughout the tables created. Or better still can i hide it and insert data with no errors thrown at me?

Thanks

Comment: If you've declared those tables as 1:1, there must be a way to get from `DonorBio` to `DonorContact`'s key -- that's `ccf_DonorBio.contact_ID; and a way to get from `DonorContact to `DonorBio`'s key -- that's why MySQL invented `ccf_DonorContact.ccf_DonorBio_donor_ID`. Are you sure you want a 1:1 cardinality? Because if there's always exactly 1 `Contact` for each `Bio` and always exactly one `Bio` for each `Contact`, you might as well put them in exactly one record together. It's more common to have 1: zero-or-one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling)